# Find if workbook for individual user exists, if workbook does not exist, create a new workbook with template

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data file that I am trying to make for each person in my work group. The data file needs to be identical to a master file as each persons data will be collected into said master file as well as an individual data file.

So far, I have the following code where I try to identify whether a user already has a workbook. I want the created workbook to have the same first four sheets as the master workbook.

The folder specified only contains the "DataFile Master" Workbook so I wouldn't expect the macro to take longer than ~5 seconds. However, when I try to run the macro, the workbook becomes non responsive.

The program does not induce an error report or indicate something to debug.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
 Sub StoreToPersonal()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ckIndWkbk = False
    folderpath = "\\netappa\Path\MACRO UPDATE WORKBOOKS" 'change to suit

    If Right(folderpath, 1) <> "\" Then folderpath = folderpath + "\"

    filename = Dir(folderpath & "*.xlsm")
    'Look through path length and find if user has an individual Workbook with a Boolean Statement

    Do While filename <> ""
      If InStr(filename, Environ("Username")) Then
        ckIndWkbk = True
      Else
    End If

    Loop

       If ckIndWkbk = False Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\netappa\Path\MACRO UPDATE WORKBOOKS\DataFile Master.xlsm")
                ws = wb.Sheets.Count
                    For Each ws In wb
                        If ws.Index > 4 Then
                            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                                ws.Delete
                            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                        End If
                    Next ws

            wb.SaveAs ("\\netappa\Path\MACRO UPDATE WORKBOOKS\\DataFile For " & Environ("Username"))

        End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You do know the file name before hand, then why do you need to loop? Check for the specific user file itself. Also, during save as, you are missing file extension.

Comment: How do I go about checking for the specific user file? And thanks for pointing out the file extension!

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out with your advice! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first `Dir` call sets the parameters and return the first file in the directory.  You need to use the `Dir` in your `Do Loop` to return subsequent files.

Note: I added `Exit Do` to after the condition is met.

[MSDN Dir Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
Sub StoreToPersonal()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ckIndWkbk = False
    folderpath = "\\netappa\Path\MACRO UPDATE WORKBOOKS"    'change to suit

    If Right(folderpath, 1) <> "\" Then folderpath = folderpath + "\"

    Filename = Dir(folderpath & "*.xlsm")
    'Look through path length and find if user has an individual Workbook with a Boolean Statement

    Do While Filename <> ""
        If InStr(Filename, Environ("Username")) Then
            ckIndWkbk = True
            Exit Do
        End If
        Filename = Dir
    Loop

    If ckIndWkbk = False Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\netappa\Path\MACRO UPDATE WORKBOOKS\DataFile Master.xlsm")
        ws = wb.Sheets.Count
        For Each ws In wb
            If ws.Index > 4 Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        Next ws

        wb.SaveAs ("\\netappa\Path\MACRO UPDATE WORKBOOKS\\DataFile For " & Environ("Username"))

    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```